# Suggestion for boot manager in external hard disk

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive, multi-boot, bootloader

I just bought an 1TB External Hard drive with eSATA, USB, FW400/800 (LaCie if you are interested).

I already put the windows 7 installation in a FAT32 active partition so i can plug the HDD via USB, since my notebook or other computers doesn't support boot via eSATA commonly, and it works.

Now i want to do more partitions so i'm looking for a way to have a boot manager as active partitions that allows me to boot from different partitions in my HDD (win7, ubuntu installations for example)

I want to know if you know any software to do this or you already have this system.

Thanks and sorry i have too many grammar errors because english is not my native language :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at using [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) (Lots of documentation there at official page).

You can do exactly what you want - have many different installers from different operating systems.

Once you get in to it, it is quite easy to work out. If you need any specific help with it - feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD installs booteasy bootmgr which merely allows to choose which partition to boot and remembers choice...